# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Drupal 7.50 Installation Requirements

Tags: server, apache2, php, drupal

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu (and Linux in general) so I apologize if I sound a bit green...

Anyways, I'm running on 16.04 LTS Ubuntu and needed to have PHP 5.6, so after following these (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788873/package-php5-have-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-04) instructions, I was able to get PHP 5.6 installed and PHP 7 removed. However, it now appears that key PHP Extensions and Database Support are disabled. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Web server  Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
OK

PHP 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
OK

```
PHP extensions  Disabled
```

Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list (see the system requirements page for more information):

```
dom
gd
SimpleXML
xml
```

Error
    Database support    Disabled
Your web server does not appear to support any common PDO database extensions. Check with your hosting provider to see if they support PDO (PHP Data Objects) and offer any databases that Drupal supports.